# What to do with Hadoop platform setup questions?

Tags: discussion

I recently noticed some questions on SO that asked things like:

> How should I setup my hadoop cluster

and

> Should I use hadoop for my problem, which stack should I use

In a way it feels like these are not right for SO (and also I am not seeing a lot of answerers flock towards these questions).

Hadoop can be used to support programming solutions, but as it is a platform these questions often touch infrastructure as well as configuration.

Now I am not sure what to do here, some options I came up with:

1. Keep the questions open on SO
2. Migrate to other site (superuser, serverfault?)
3. Vote to close

Comment: What to do with an off topic question? Difficult to say...

Comment: @Braiam Perhaps it will help if I will elaborate: First of all I am not sure whether the questions are properly off topic (in FAQ what should I ask exceptions, example 5 and 6 may or may not apply **sufficiently**). IF the question is deemed were off topic both the migration suggestion for Superuser and Serverfault seem to be plausible options.

Answer (score 2):

The specific examples you mentioned are clearly Too Broad. They're not answerable without asking for a lot more details about the configuration needs than provided. No other justification is needed to close a question with only that content.

However, it's important to realize that Hadoop is not *always* off-topic. It clearly falls into [software tools commonly used by programmers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), so being about Hadoop alone is not reason enough to close it. Questions that are actually about the workings or configuration almost certainly affect programming tasks, so they're on topic.

It's difficult to draw an exact line for what constitutes "programming tasks" and what doesn't. For example, no one complains about questions detailing problems installing Python packages, as this is just something programmers have to do. Strictly speaking, this can only be relevant for configuring the environment before you write any code. So does installing Hadoop count as a programming task, which would allow users to ask questions if they get an error? Since there isn't a clear, objective line, there isn't much point in trying to be strict about it. If it is clear, reasonably scoped, and answerable, leave it alone. At worst, it's also on topic elsewhere and may result in a cross-site dupe.

Comment: Not being a "problem that is unique to software development" is enough to close it. Is the *raison d'etre* of SO. That line is joined by an AND, not an OR.

Comment: @Braiam Then I guess every SQL question should be on DBA. Every bash or PowerShell question needs to be closed immediately, too. Doesn't matter if it's in a script or in code or not because it's not unique enough, right? Oh, and git can be used by non-programmers, too! That *clearly* isn't the meaning they intend in the help text. That is an absurd level of pedantry.

Comment: Just to check whether I understand correctly: You state that if they are too broad, then close (which makes sense), and if they are not too broad then SO is the right site for them? (Not SF or SU)

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin Questions can be on topic on multiple sites. So it's conceivable that some questions might be on topic on both SO and SF. The problem lies in trying to draw a hard line between software development and system administration. The two are inextricably connected and involve some amount of overlap. But other than saying SU or SF *wouldn't* be appropriate, yes.